# Javascript documment write

Tags: javascript

tengo un error en esta línea de código, sin embargo no se como solucionarlo alguien podria ayudarme por favor :)

```
    document.write("<td id=\"text_login\"><font color=\""+cletra+"\" face=\""+tletra+"\" size=\"1\">"+text_login+"</font></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"xu2sr98z\" id=\"input_login\" size=\"16\" maxlength=\"16\"></td></tr><tr>");
    document.write("<td id=\"text_pass\"><font color=\""+cletra+"\" face=\""+tletra+"\" size=\"1\">"+text_pwd+"</font></td>");
    document.write("<td><input type=\"password\" name=\"wps1zap3\" id=\"input_pass\" size=\"8\" maxlength=\"8\" onkeypress=\"capLock(event);
    CambiarUrl(event);
    \"></td></tr><tr>");
    document.write("<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p_clasica\" id=\"p_clasica\" size=\"16\" maxlength=\"16\"></td></tr><tr>");
    document.write("<tr align=\"center\">");
    document.write("<td colspan=\"2\"><b><font color=\""+cletra+"\" face=\""+tletra+"\" size=\"1\">");
    document.write("<a href=\"javascript:recordar_pwd();
    \">"+text_olvido+"</a></td></tr>");
    document.write("<tr><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">");
```

Con el permiso de ustedes me tomo el atrevimiento de publicar el código completo, si alguien me puede ayudar a corregir los errores porque me esta dando errores de sintaxis.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por que usas document.write? no sería mas fácil y limpio obtener ese td y agregarle desde JS el contenido dinámico?

Comment: @BetaM Realmente es un código de inserción que genera una página web, la verdad es que lo estoy usando de esa forma porque ya está creado así, pero ese error hace que no cargue el formulario supongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema realmente surge debido a que le estás asignando dos funciones al evento `onkeypress`, por lo que entiendo los eventos en HTML solo tiene la capacidad de recibir una función definida en Javascript.

```
onkeypress=\"capLock(event);CambiarUrl(event);\">
```

Vi que inteste usar `\` para solucionar el problema que causan las comillas. Te recuerdo que en ES6 existe el template string con comillas invertidas (``).

Como dije este evento solo se podría agregar a la etiqueta con una sola función.

La concatenación con template string:

```
document.write(`
    <td><input type="password" name="wps1zap3" id="input_pass" size="8" maxlength="8" onkeypress="capLock(event)"></td></tr><tr>
    `);
```

También me gustaría darte unas recomendaciones:

- El evento `onkeypress` no es recomendado de usar, según la [documentación de Modzilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress):

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes.

- Estos son muchos `document.write`, te recomiendo usar un documento HTML. Si el sao es que desea añadir contenido de manera dinámica , existe el atributo `innerHTML` del documento.

Espero te haya servido.

### Edición:

El contenido que se asigna al atributo `innerHTML` es el contenido que tendrá el elemento dueño de dicho atributo. Para usarlo en Javascript, solo es necesario tener un método selector (de cualquier tipo) del elemento HTML. Para el ejemplo que voy a dar, voy a usar el método `getElementById()` que es el más común de usar y solo requiere un string con el id del elemento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Ejemplo
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="contenedor">
        
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const elemento  = document.getElementById("contenedor");
        elemento.innerHTML = "Ahora tengo contenido";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí se almacena el selector en una constante, y se asigna un valor al atributo del selector. Es igual de válido hacer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = "Ahora tengo contenido";
    </script>
```

**No es necesario que todo esté en el mismo archivo**. Puedes acceder con los mismo métodos selectores estando en otro archivo (.js):

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Usando otros selectores:**

Existen otros selectores de elementos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.innerHTML = "Estamos activos xD";
</script>
```

Hay otros, pero creo que los puedes investigar por tu propia cuenta.

Espero mi explicación te haya servido.

Comment: Algun ejemplo de cómo usaría el innerHTML, lo mas dummy posible muchas gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Revisa la edición que acabo de hacer a mi respuesta.

Comment: También te puedes revisar [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) xD.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código, lo recomendable es que revises las uniones del código y que juegues con las comillas simples y las dobles ( Dentro de las Simples Se Quedan Las Dobles Bien Puestas ) Así que lo demás estaba erróneo...

A lo mejor hay un document write que te funcione mal pero eso tienes que ver-lo tu en las funciones que llamas...

```js
document.write("<td id=\"text_login\"><font color=\""+cletra+"\" face=\""+tletra+"\" size=\"1\">"+text_login+"</font></td>");
    document.write('<td><input type="\text\" name="\xu2sr98z\" id="\input_login\" size="\16\" maxlength="\16\"></td></tr><tr>');
    
    document.write("<td id=\"text_pass\"><font color=\""+cletra+"\" face=\""+tletra+"\" size=\"1\">"+text_pwd+"</font></td>");
    var n = capLock(event);
    var r = CambiarUrl(event);
    document.write('<td><input type="\password\" name="\wps1zap3\" id="\input_pass\" size="\8\" maxlength="\8\" onkeypress="\ + n + r + "\"></td></tr><tr>');
    
    document.write('<td><input type="\hidden\" name="\p_clasica\" id="\p_clasica\" size="\16\" maxlength="\16\"></td></tr><tr>');
    document.write('<tr align=\"center\">');
    document.write('<td colspan="\2\"><b><font color= "\"' + cletra + '"\" face=\" "' + tletra + '"\" size="\1\">');
    document.write('<a href="\"' + javascript:recordar_pwd() +
    '"\">' + text_olvido + '"</a></td></tr>');
    document.write('<tr><td colspan="\2\" align="\center\">');
```